# jQuery multiple selector chaining

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to rewrite the following javascript to jQuery (output immediately underneath):

```
document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
```

20131020_143909.jpg (2.6 mb) 100%

20131020_143934.jpg (2.6 mb) 100%

20131020_144435.jpg (2.8 mb) 100%

jQuery code (output immediately underneath):

```
$("#" + file.id + ", b").html("<span>" + file.percent + "%</span>");
```

100%

98%

20131020_144435.jpg (2.8 mb) 98%

The javascript code works perfectly but my jQuery code is not producing the same result as the javascript code.

Comment: I really don't know what the html actually looks like since it is is created by a library called plupload. This is the first time I work with jQuery and converted some other js code to jquery with no problem but I cannot get the js above to convert.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma in the selector

```
$("#" + file.id + " b").html("<span>" + file.percent + "%</span>");
```

You're selecting both the *file* element and its `b` descendant and overwriting them, not just the `b`.

Comment: `$("#" + file.id + " > b")` also work, if `b` is immediate child.

Comment: What a perfect eye you have! Thank you!